# How to change XDEBUG_CONFIG idekey value in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have configured PhpStorm to connect to a remote web server. I am running phpunit for unit tests. I have xdebug running and have created an ssh tunnel for debugging. I know xdebug is running as I am able to click and run a phpunit test (with breakpoint set) by just clicking the run button (after turning on listening for PHP debug connections).  However if I instead choose the Debug option in PhpStorm I get connection errors.

Enabling debug messages to the PhpStorm log file I see that the command being sent is:

```
DEBUG - ellij.ssh.SshConnectionService - Executing SSH command: 
cd /[path to project files]; 
exec env "IDE_PHPUNIT_CUSTOM_LOADER"="/[path to autoloader]/autoload.php" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "XDEBUG_CONFIG"="idekey=17650" /usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9002 -dxdebug.remote_host=[ip address] /[path to phpunit]/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /[path to phpunit xml file]/phpunit.xml --filter '/(::myTestClassMethod)( .*)?$/' 'another method being tested' /[path to unit test file]/myUnitTest.php --teamcity within SshjSshConnection([blah]@[foo])@bar
```

My php.ini settings are expecting `idekey=PHPSTORM` but I'm seeing a numeric key in the command line that keeps changing for each attempt.

I'm assuming these two values for `idekey` need to match. If that's correct how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't need to match. In fact, PhpStorm is just overriding it here so that it can match against what it expects.

I don't understand why it does that, as *IDE Keys* are (currently) only used in combination with [DBGp proxies](https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgp#just-in-time-debugging-and-debugger-proxies).

As you don't describe what *"connection errors"* are, it's not really possible to provide an answer to that part of the question yet.

Comment: Thanks Derick! Good to know they don't need to match. I'm sort of grasping at various straws trying to figure out the connection problem.

Comment: When I choose to 'Debug' a method (vs. just Run) my test will run remotely and I also get an error from the phpstorm debug window:
"Connection was not established. Cannot start debugger session with 'Xdebug 2.9.1' Validate installation' 
Clicking the Validate installation link I get another pop-up with a link to view the php info. Looking at the xdebug settings from there I notice the remote_enable setting is off. I've double checked on the remote server using php -i on the command line and by uploading a php/html file with phpinfo() and in both cases xdebug.remote_enable is on.

Comment: It's plausible that the PHP that PhpStorm starts is not the same as the one you run when you type `php -i`. Are there multiple PHP binaries installed?

Comment: I made some other setting changes to my ini file and looked at the info that PhpStorm was reporting and those other settings were getting picked up ok. So it's just the remote_enable that was getting switched off. After a few hours of trial and error I finally stumbled upon the 'Pass required configuration options through command line' checkbox on the PHP Debug preferences advanced settings. Unchecking that box did the trick. Woo!